# How to replace only the last character in a string but not earlier occurrences of the same character?

Tags: python

I want to find which word's last character is 'e' and I would like to replace 'e' with 'ing'. After this process want to append these in the array such as new words

```
words= ['example', 'serve', 'recognize', 'ale']


for x in words:
    size = len(x)
    if "e" == x[size - 1]:
       words.append(x.replace(x[-1], 'ing'))

print(words)
```

output

```
['example', 'serve', 'recognize', 'ale', 'ingxampling', 'singrving', 'ringcognizing', 'aling']
```

I want to get the output like this

```
['example', 'serve', 'recognize', 'ale', 'exampling', 'serving', 'recognizing', 'aling']
```

Comment: To get the last char in a string use `s[-1]`

Comment: `replace` replaces *all* the matching characters in the string, not just the last one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
words = ['example', 'serve', 'recognize', 'ale']

for x in words:
    if x[-1] == 'e':
       words.append(x[:-1] + 'ing')

print(words)
```

Or if you want a 1 liner:

```
words = [*words, *[x[:-1] + 'ing' for x in words if x[-1] == 'e']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to saradartur's solution but with filtering (I also added the use of `str.endswith`):

```py
words = ['example', 'serve', 'recognize', 'ale']
words.extend(word[:-1] + 'ing' for word in words if word.endswith('e'))
print(words)
```

**Output**

```
['example', 'serve', 'recognize', 'ale', 'exampling', 'serving', 'recognizing', 'aling']
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "How to get last character in string on Python?" is quite simple:

```
my_string = "hello"

last_char = last_char = my_string[-1:]
print(last_char)

>>> o
```

This can then be applied to solving what your code is trying to do:

```
words= ['example', 'serve', 'recognize', 'ale']

for x in words:
    last_char = x[-1:]
    if last_char == "e":
        words.append(x[:-1]+"ing")

print(words)

>>> ['example', 'serve', 'recognize', 'ale', 'exampling', 'serving', 'recognizing', 'aling']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't really want to *get* the last character but *check* the last character. Anyway, a version that can handle arbitrarily long suffixes:

```
>>> suffix, replacement = 'e', 'ing'
>>> for word in words:
        if word.endswith(suffix):
            print(word.removesuffix(suffix) + replacement)

exampling
serving
recognizing
aling
```